# How to change url appearance of internal links?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, apache

Currently I am working on a sample project which is a single page website where all the details are divided in sections.
I am calling all the section through internal linking and I want to modify the url structure of those links from like "example.com/#section-1" to "example.com/about-us". So, how can I achieve this?
The following is a sample code structure.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, body *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      body, html, div{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
      }
      #container-1{
        background-color:green;
      }
      #container-2{
        background-color:yellow;
      }
      #container-3{
        background-color:gray;
      }
      .container p{
        padding:10px;
        font-size:50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main-container">
      <div id="container-1" class="container"><p>Container-1</p><a href="#container-2">To Container-2</a></div>
      <div id="container-2" class="container"><p>Container-2</p><a href="#container-3">To Container-3</a></div>
      <div id="container-3" class="container"><p>Container-3</p><a href="#container-1">To Container-1</a></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `about-us` or `contact-us` instead of `container-1` or `container-2`.

Comment: I can use them but, I am getting the '#' symbol in the url which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method).

So here is the steps:

1. Get the relative URL from the clicked link.
2. Use `pushState` to push the state to the history (so you could use back and forward.
3. Scroll the page to the selected element.

**Keep it in you mind** that you need to configure your server that wil transfer (rewrite) any sub page to the main page. So when user will try to go to "sub page" (`container2` for example) the server will return the main page, and with the javascript you will scroll to page to the right section.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = a.hash.replace('#', '');
    history.pushState(null, 'page', link);
    scrollToElement();
  });
});

function scrollToElement() {
  var page = location.pathname.replace('/', ''),
      container = document.querySelector('#' + page);

  container.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, body *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      body, html, div{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
      }
      #container-1{
        background-color:green;
      }
      #container-2{
        background-color:yellow;
      }
      #container-3{
        background-color:gray;
      }
      .container p{
        padding:10px;
        font-size:50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main-container">
      <div id="container-1" class="container"><p>Container-1</p><a href="#container-2">To Container-2</a></div>
      <div id="container-2" class="container"><p>Container-2</p><a href="#container-3">To Container-3</a></div>
      <div id="container-3" class="container"><p>Container-3</p><a href="#container-1">To Container-1</a></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/zaduqo

Comment: It's working. But on my local machine it's not working and it is giving me this error "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///D:/x/container-2' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL ". I don't know why?

And can you please explain me if you don't mind as how did it work as I am a new learner towards JavaScript.

Comment: I think you need to run it from local server rather than file system ([tutorial how to create local server here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Set_up_a_basic_working_environment)).

Comment: Okay. I'll try. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It works my friend, but, when I am using this on a live server and for example I am typing example.com/container-1 then I am receiving a file not found error from the host.

Comment: Read `Keep it in you mind` note. [How to configure Apache to deal with pushState](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/apache-htaccess-for-html5-push-state-manipulations)

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend using Apache **mod_rewrite** module

```
RewriteRule ^/about-us /index.php#container-2 [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/contact-us /index.php#container-1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

and then using

```
<a href="about-us">links</a>
```

Comment: Sorry my friend bu it didn't work. The host says the file does not exist.